# Ajax Accordion problem with css display:list-item;

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an accordion control extender in my page which is works fine, I added a css file to show the  as a list, it is working perfectly in all the borwsers, but in IE compatibility view the list-style-type:square; is displaced and also there is one additional square added to top. is it a bug?

The CSS being used:

```
.accordionHeader { 
    border: 1px solid Silver; 
    color: Navy;
    background-color: White;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height:15px;
    display:list-item;
    list-style-position:inside;
    list-style-type:square;
}
```

Is there any other way I can show the accordion as a list?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That bug even has a name: IE :-).

Impossible to help you without going through the css & html but you could try to add a reset css fix like the one from Eric Meyer:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.

regards,
Stijn

Comment: this is the css file

.accordionHeader
{
    border: 1px solid Silver;
    color: Navy;
    background-color: White;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height:15px;    
    display:list-item;
    list-style-position:inside;
    list-style-type:square;
     
}